# Reboot after specified time in cloud-init, only once

Tags: cloud-init

*This is on a CentOS 7 AWS image built off the official AMI*

The power_state module is exactly what I need, looking at this

http://cloudinit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/examples.html#reboot-poweroff-when-finished

However...  I can't find anywhere in the documentation that says where to put this or run it.  I also need it to run only once.

Should I put it directly into /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg?  Should it go under /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/foo.cfg?

This tool is really interesting and powerful, but I'm scratching my head over the seemingly complete lack of documentation! :(

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html

Answer (score 0):

cloud-init will consume data that you pass when starting a VM. Depending on the cloud provider, you can pass user data on the UI, CLI or API.

On AWS, you can do this on the CLI for example: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/launching-instance.html#configure_instance_details_step

with the user-data option.